# ansible could not find the exposed command in the environment variable on the remote host

Tags: java, ubuntu, ansible

I want to use Ansible to execute the command to view the Java version on a remote host,However, the return result does not find the Java command.

My ansible-playbook is as follows:

```
---
- shell:
   cmd: 'source /root/.bashrc && java -version'
   executable: /bin/bash
  register: result
- debug:
    var: result
```

When I executed the following error occurred：

```
TASK [test : shell] *************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [192.168.1.70]: FAILED! => {"ansible_facts": {"discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python3"}, "changed": true, "cmd": "source /root/.bashrc && java -version", "delta": "0:00:00.002934", "end": "2021-02-03 15:59:29.904640", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 127, "start": "2021-02-03 15:59:29.901706", "stderr": "/bin/bash: java: command not found", "stderr_lines": ["/bin/bash: java: command not found"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

The content of this file `/root/.bashrc`is as follows:

```
...
JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_271
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export PATH
```

The software version is as follows：
ansible: 2.9.6
python: 3.8.5
ubuntu: 20.04.1 LTS and 5.4.0-65-generic core

Comment: What I mean is that java commands can be executed directly after connecting to the remote host,Because I can directly execute ```java -version``` on the remote host.

Comment: ```ansible test -m shell -a 'java -version'
``` just this commond

Comment: Yes,I mean ansible will parse this file ```/root/.bashrc```, I configured it like this, but it still can’t find the java command.this is my problemt.

Comment: Ansible modules [shell](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/shell_module.html) and [command](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/command_module.html#ansible-collections-ansible-builtin-command-module) don't read the `.bashrc` files. They run `/bin/sh` by default. If you want Ansible to parse `.bashrc` you have to explicitly tell it. If you have a problem make it [mre].

Comment: Okay, the ```source``` command is resolved, but the ```java``` command can’t find the problem still exists

Answer (score 0):

Q: **"*Ansible shall parse /root/.bashrc*"**

A: Export *JAVA_HOME*

```sh
shell> cat /root/.bashrc
...
JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_271
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export PATH
export JAVA_HOME
```

and *source* the resources before the command

```yaml
- shell:
    cmd: 'source /root/.bashrc; java -version'
    executable: /bin/bash
  become: true
```

---

Quoiting from [Notes](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/shell_module.html#notes)

> *"If you want to execute a command securely and predictably, it may be better to use the ansible.builtin.command module instead. Best practices when writing playbooks will follow the trend of using ansible.builtin.command unless the ansible.builtin.shell module is explicitly required."*

---

Example. Given the files

```sh
shell> ssh admin@test_11 cat /root/.bashrc
export PATH=/scratch:${PATH}

shell> ssh admin@test_11 cat /scratch/test.bash
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
echo $PATH
```

The playbook

```yaml
- hosts: test_11
  tasks:
    - shell:
        cmd: "source /root/.bashrc; test.bash"
        executable: /usr/local/bin/bash
      register: result
      become: true
    - debug:
        var: result.stdout
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [test_11] => 
  result.stdout: /scratch:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

The same result gives the *command* task below

```yaml
    - command: "/usr/local/bin/bash -c 'source /root/.bashrc; test.bash'"
      register: result
      become: true
```

Comment: ```
- shell:
   cmd: 'java -version'
   executable: /bin/bash
  become: true
  register: result
- debug:
    var: result
```
I executed it through play-book, but it still can’t find the java command

Answer (score 0):

```
- name: test
  gather_facts: false
  hosts: test
  environment:
    PATH: /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_271/bin
  tasks:
     - shell:
         cmd: 'java -version'
         executable: /bin/bash
       register: result
     - debug:
         var: result
```

It is correct to expose the environment variables of the java command in this way.